# Haxe / hscript - Prevent exposing certain methods to scripts

Tags: haxe, hxcpp

So, I've created "interface class" with all static methods, which I want to expose to `hscript` scripts. It looks like this:

```
package com.application.interfaces.Terrain;

import com.application.TerrainCore

class Terrain {

    private static var terrain:TerrainCore;

    public static function _init(inTerrain:TerrainCore):Void {
        terrain = inTerrain;
    }

    public static function test(s:Int):Void {
        terrain.test(s);
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I need to set `terrain` object somehow, but I don't want it to be exposed to scripts. I expose whole classes with

```
var interp = new Interp();
var module = Type.resolveClass("com.application.interfaces.Terrain");
interp.variables.set("Terrain", module)
```

The idea was to override method `call` in `hscript.Interp` so it doesn't execute any method named `_init`, but I don't know how to do that. Original `call` method looks like this:

```
function call( o : Dynamic, f : Dynamic, args : Array<Dynamic> ) : Dynamic {
    return Reflect.callMethod(o,f,args);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use a class instance of Terrain instead of using static members? Eg:

```
interp.variables.set("Terrain", new Terrain(new TerrainCore()));
```

Script users wont know if they are using static or instance methods as it will still be access via:

```
Terrain.test(123);
```

in script.

Another option (based on clemos), is to use rtti to work out what is allowed (instead of maintaining a list of it), eg:

```
Terrain._init(new TerrainCore());
```

_init is a private function now, so you need to `@:allow` it from your calling class (see below), also, you need to annotate with `@:rtti` so you can grab info about the functions at runtime, so Terrain now looks like:

```
@:rtti
class Terrain {

    private static var terrain:TerrainCore;

    @:allow(test.hscript.demo.Main)
    private static function _init(inTerrain:TerrainCore):Void {
        terrain = inTerrain;
    }

    public static function test(s:Int):Void {
        terrain.test(s);
    }
}
```

Finally, the script interp `fcall` now honours whether a field is public or private, ie:

```
public override function fcall(o:Dynamic, f:String, args:Array<Dynamic>):Dynamic 
    var rtti = haxe.rtti.Rtti.getRtti(o);
    for (field in rtti.statics) {
        if (field.name == f && field.isPublic == false) {
            error(EInvalidAccess(f));
        }
    }
    return super.fcall(o, f, args);
}
```

Its worth noting that I used `statics` rather than `fields` for obvious reasons. Im also not sure what overhead this would cause with the loop and the rtti.

Comment: Yes, I shouldn't used static members here in the first place, it didn't occur to me that I can use class instances somehow. Thank you. Btw, @clemos and your other solution would also be a possibility, but using instances seems more elegant solution in my case, I shouldn't use static methods for what I am currently doing...

Comment: Yeah you're both right.
Also, you may probably want to have different access at compile-time and at "interpretation time";
If I were you, I'd use metadata (such as `@:hscriptAccess('public')`) to control access at interpretation time, rather than `public` / `private`, that are rather for compile-time : http://haxe.org/manual/lf-metadata.html

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's `fcall` you should override, as `call` is used for toplevel calls only :

https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hscript/blob/master/hscript/Interp.hx#L328-L331

It should be easy to filter `f` argument like :

```
if ( FORBIDDEN_FIELDS.indexOf( f ) > -1 ) throw EInvalidAccess( f );
```

or

```
if ( f.indexOf('_') == 0 ) throw EInvalidAccess( f );
```